# How to table minus table = answer PHP MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have a table in MYSQL like this:

```
ID | Team  | DPV | DPT | Difference |
1  | Team1 | 25  | 27  |            |
2  | Team2 | 24  | 14  |            |
```

I want to do a math on DPV and DPT so like:

DPV minus DPT = Difference

**I have now:**  e2teams is my tablename.

```
SELECT FROM e2teams GROUP by Difference HAVING COUNT DPV (-) DPT;
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Multiple things I'm afraid. You aren't specifying what your are selecting. The `count` bit looks invalid (it is supposed to count the number of results returned by the query, i.e. what you are grouping by). `Having` expects some kind of true/false thing, but count() would return a number if it was called correctly. You are also grouping by a column that seems to have no data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one:

```
SELECT ID, Team, DPV, DPT, DPV-DPT AS Difference FROM e2teams
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Team,
    DPV,
    DPT,
    (DPV - DPT) as Difference
FROM
    e2teams
```

You can find more information **[here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html)**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM e2teams GROUP by Difference HAVING (DPV-DPT) = Difference ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid errors and database corruption, you should never have a calculable value on you database.

So the best way to do this is, as answered before :

```
SELECT ID, Team, DPV, DPT, (DPV-DPT) as Difference FROM e2teams
```